# How can I make a Nix package that has both Python and Haskell packages?

Tags: python, haskell, nix

I have a shell.nix for a Python development environment that looks like this:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

( let
    colormath = pkgs.python37Packages.buildPythonPackage rec {
      pname = "colormath";
      version = "3.0.0";

      src = pkgs.python37Packages.fetchPypi{
        inherit version;
        inherit pname;
        sha256 = "05qjycgxp3p2f9n6lmic68sxmsyvgnnlyl4z9w7dl9s56jphaiix";
      };

      buildInputs = [ pkgs.python37Packages.numpy pkgs.python37Packages.networkx ];
    };

  in pkgs.python37.buildEnv.override rec {
        extraLibs = with pkgs.python37Packages; [
          matplotlib
          spacy
          pandas
          spacy_models.en_core_web_md
          jupyter
          scikitlearn
          nltk
          altair
          vega_datasets
          cherrypy
          dominate
          plotly
          colormath
          falcon # Spacy server
        ];
      }
  ).env
```

But now I also want to add Haskell code, and Haskell dependencies to that project. How can I do that? I can only find instructions in the Nix documentation for *either* Python *or* Haskell project shell.nix configs, so I don't know how to combine them.

Comment: `pkgs.python37.buildEnv` is, I think, a wrapper around the builtin `buildEnv` function, which is language-agnostic.

Comment: So what would it look like to rewrite this using just buildEnv?

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond my Nix abilities at this point; I'm hoping someone comes along to provide such an answer in the time it would take me to figure it out.